# My icon doesn't want to change size

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, icons

I've created a button on my page and I want to increase the icon size. However the icon size doesn't want to change when I try to change the styling, can someone please help me? I'm sure it's something stupid that I'm missing out on.

Button/icon code:

```
<button style="margin:0 auto; height:70px;" class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="removeCard()"><span class="icon ion-ios7-close-outline light"></span></button>
```

Comment: Hi, your icon come from a web-font? a cutom css with picture ?

Comment: try and use `padding`

Comment: If it's form web-font try font-size: ____px property

Comment: It's from this site http://ionicons.com/

Answer (score 1):

are you using some framework? Semantic UI, Bootstrap or Foundation?

Anyhow, you can try 2 things:

Change: `<span class="icon ion-ios7-close-outline light"></span>` to

this : `<span class="large icon ion-ios7-close-outline light"></span>`

or you can try this:

`<span class="icon ion-ios7-close-outline light" style="width:50px; height:50px;"></span>`

Just my thoughts

Comment: This doesn't work and I'm using bootstrap :)

Comment: <span class="icon ion-ios7-close-outline light" style="font-size=50px"></span> Setting g The font size should do iT then, like the other answer mentions :)

Answer (score 1):

For a web font you should use *font-size* css property

Concider you are working with a font as arial or times